# How to use Contains in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();         
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
String hql ="from CustomObjectId where CONTAINS(fileName,fileName)";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("fileName", fileName);
List file=query.list();
tx.commit();
```

How can I search `CONTAINS`?

Comment: CustomObjectId  is table name.fileName is column name

Comment: fileName is the column where contains need to check

Comment: Sakthi:: Can you post your query ? Some how it is deleted and I could not see any history.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IN clause as shown below:

```
 session = sessionFactory.openSession();         
String hql =" from CustomObjectId c where c.fileName in :fileName";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("fileName", fileName);
List file=query.list();
```

Also, you DO NOT need a transaction (explicitly) to only READ from database. So, just remove `Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); and tx.commit();` lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `Hibernate Criteria`.

```
String fileNames[] = {"fileName1", "fileName2"};
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CustomObjectId.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.in("fileName ", fileNames));
List list = criteria.list();
```